# c# Dictionary not throwing KeyNotFound exception?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Why does this code not throw KeyNotFound exception?

```
var tempDic = new Dictionary<long, string>{{1,"a"},{2,"b"},{3,"c"}};

        var realDic = new Dictionary<long, string>{{1,"Z"}};

        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE:");

        foreach (var item in tempDic)
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"TempDic: {item.Key} : {item.Value}");
        }

        foreach (var item in realDic)
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"realDic: {item.Key} : {item.Value}");
        }

        foreach (var key in tempDic.Keys)
        {
           if (!realDic.ContainsKey(key))
           {
              realDic[key] = tempDic[key];
           }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER:");


        foreach (var item in tempDic)
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"TempDic: {item.Key} : {item.Value}");
        }

        foreach (var item in realDic)
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"realDic: {item.Key} : {item.Value}");
        }
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Where would you expect it to throw? There is nothing in the code that should throw this exception according to the flow of the program...

Comment: ["A set operation creates a new element with the specified key"](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item).

Comment: Why should it? You aren't trying to access to *read* any non-existing key, you're *adding* new keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Dictionary, `realDic[key] = tempDic[key];` is another way to say `realDic.Add(key, tempDic[key]);`. However, checking .NET source code, the `Add(key, tempDic[key])` call will result in calling [`Insert`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,186) method.

That's the reason why a `KeyNotFoundException` isn't thrown.

There's anyway a difference, explained in the [MSDN documentation, regarding `Add` method, "Remarks" section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_Add__0__1_):

> You can also use the `Item[TKey]` property to add new elements by
>   setting the value of a key that does not exist in the
>   `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>;` for example, `myCollection[myKey] = myValue`
>   (in Visual Basic, `myCollection(myKey) = myValue`). However, if the
>   specified key already exists in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, setting
>   the `Item[TKey]` property overwrites the old value. In contrast, ***the Add
>   method throws an exception if a value with the specified key already
>   exists.***

Comment: With the difference that `Add` will throw an exception if there is already a record for the key your trying to add and the setter of the index does an "upsert".

Comment: Actually setter calls [Insert](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,186) method

Comment: Yep, thanks @IPValverde. I updated the answer, but I didn't read your comment yet.

Comment: @AleksAndreev Perhaps too late, but thanks for pointing out what happens behind the scenes!

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs).

Indexer looks this (remeber, you call the setter):

```
public TValue this[TKey key] {
    get {
        int i = FindEntry(key);
        if (i >= 0) return entries[i].value;
        ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
        return default(TValue);
    }
    set {
        Insert(key, value, false);
    }
}
```

where `Insert` is:

```
private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add) {    
    if( key == null ) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }

    if (buckets == null) Initialize(0);
    int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
    int collisionCount = 0;
#endif

    for (int i = buckets[targetBucket]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
        if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) {
            if (add) { 
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_AddingDuplicate);
            }
            entries[i].value = value;
            version++;
            return;
        } 

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
        collisionCount++;
#endif
    }
    int index;
    if (freeCount > 0) {
        index = freeList;
        freeList = entries[index].next;
        freeCount--;
    }
    else {
        if (count == entries.Length)
        {
            Resize();
            targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
        }
        index = count;
        count++;
    }

    entries[index].hashCode = hashCode;
    entries[index].next = buckets[targetBucket];
    entries[index].key = key;
    entries[index].value = value;
    buckets[targetBucket] = index;
    version++;

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING

#if FEATURE_CORECLR
    // In case we hit the collision threshold we'll need to switch to the comparer which is using randomized string hashing
    // in this case will be EqualityComparer<string>.Default.
    // Note, randomized string hashing is turned on by default on coreclr so EqualityComparer<string>.Default will 
    // be using randomized string hashing
     if (collisionCount > HashHelpers.HashCollisionThreshold && comparer == NonRandomizedStringEqualityComparer.Default) 
    {
        comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>) EqualityComparer<string>.Default;
        Resize(entries.Length, true);
    }
#else
    if(collisionCount > HashHelpers.HashCollisionThreshold && HashHelpers.IsWellKnownEqualityComparer(comparer)) 
    {
        comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>) HashHelpers.GetRandomizedEqualityComparer(comparer);
        Resize(entries.Length, true);
    }
#endif // FEATURE_CORECLR

#endif
}
```

It gives the behavior you observe. If `key` does not exists it is added and corresponding `value` **is set anyway**.